# Can a neural network learn to choose the arbitrary point nearest a fixed point?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to determine whether I'm using neural networks properly. This is the scenario:

I have a 2D rectangular world. In it, I randomly position 3 crystals. My hero begins in the center. I want the AI to move him to the nearest crystal. Of course this is a trivial geometry problem, but I'm trying to solve it via neural network, as an exercise.

My approach has been to send the inputs as serial coordinates, like this: [X0, Y0, X1, Y1, X2, Y2]. The output is the position of the nearest crystal, as coordinates [X, Y].

I've modeled this in TensorFlow without success. I've generated up to 1M cases, and run it with a variety of neuron counts, hidden layers, learning rates, epochs, activation functions and initialization schemes. So far, it doesn't seem able to approximate the correct XY. All predictions are very close to the center.

I *have* had success with other simple exercises, such as 'determine whether a random point is within a pre-defined box', so I'm somewhat confident in the code. I just don't know if I'm attempting something impossible.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the capabilities of neural networks? Is there something wrong with my input/output? So far I have only used feed-forward models... maybe I need to try a recurrent network?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Are you doing a regression or a classification, for a suggestion it looks like you are performing a regression so in that case you are getting values near center. You can try performing the same operation by encoding the coordinates and converting the problem into classification problem. And you can also try looking up for restricted boltzman machine for solution of this kind of solution.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info! I will look into restricted boltzman machines.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar It is regression, yes. That was my goal in this exercise (I already solved it as classification, and chose this next). As an update, I have added hidden layers, and changed to ReLU activation and heNormal initialization, and am getting now getting good results. I will probably answer this myself with the details. Thanks again!